# HTML non-hierarchical tags

Tags: html

I don't think it's the case but I'm still taking the shot: Is there such a thing as a non-hierarchical tag in HTML (for markup independent of content structure).
For instance, something like:

```html
<div class="thingy" id="thing">
blabla<n-htag>bla
</div>
<div class="thingy" id="thing2">
John Dodelidoo</n-htag>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd bet dollars to donuts this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). The answer is "no" but the real question is _why_?

Comment: That is an invalid HTML

Comment: It makes sense based on the content your HTML holds. Since you have not shared the exact contents, it's difficult to suggest the right HTML. Moreover, what does `n-htag` mean? It's invalid as it has a missing end tag and a start tag. Overall, it's an invalid tag too

Comment: @Mr.Alien that is OP's question though... are there any HTML tags that are allowed outside of the DOM hierarchy... tags that can start and end anywhere, regardless of structure. I bet they want to use forms with table rows 

Comment: ah yes, I see, anyways it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as a XY problem.
It's just that, considering the HTML tags used for formatting the target document, I wanted to keep a meta-data-based trace over the source of the text. But this tagging, indeed span-like, has to be independent from the HTML formating.
Therefore I was asking if there's a solution for non-hierchical tags.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT**: I'm realizing now what you're asking is that you want a tag where you can group multiple tags together but being completely unrelated to the HTML structure (e.x. you could start it in the middle of one element and end it in the middle of another that is completely isolated). Because of the way XML is structured, you cannot; it is completely based on hierarchy (as far as I can tell).

*For archival purposes, the original answer is below.*

---

If I understand what you're asking, the closest thing we have to that (as far as I can remember) is `<span>`: while it doesn't change the visual appearance of the page, it allows you to group elements. (And obviously, while you aren't REQUIRED to indent it, you can).

Comment: @AlonEitan My bad, I misunderstood the question. I've edited my answer accordingly.